# Where is the variable definition in this simple line of code?

Tags: c

I'm a little confused about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
int x;
int main()
{
    int x;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Where is the variable definition in this code? I'm assuming that it would be the external variable. In that case, shouldn't the variable in the function have an extern modifier?

What if the external variable was below the main function?

Comment: Definition of WHICH function?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the variable definition of x.

Comment: there are 2 variables `x` one global and one local. Inside main, the local definition of `x` shadows the global one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern` doesn't mean outside the current scope, it means an object with external linkage. An automatic variable never has external linkage, so your declaration `int x` inside main can't possibly refer to that. Hence it's hiding the global `int x`, that is, the the variable x with `auto` storage class is hiding the global x. You need to read more about [storage classes in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_storage_classes.htm)
Refer the below program AFTER reading about them :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i = 6;
int main()
{
    int i = 4;
    printf("%d\n", i); /* prints 4 */
    {
        extern int i; /* this i is now "current". */
        printf("%d\n", i); /* prints 6 */
        {
            int *x = &i; /* Save the address of the "old" i,
                          * before making a new one. */
            int i = 32; /* one more i. Becomes the "current" i.*/
            printf("%d\n", i); /* prints 32 */
            printf("%d\n", *x); /* prints 6 - "old" i through a pointer.*/
        }
        /* The "previous" i goes out of scope.
         * That extern one is "current" again. */
        printf("%d\n", i); /* prints 6 again */
    }
    /* That extern i goes out of scope.
     * The only remaining i is now "current". */
    printf("%d\n", i); /* prints 4 again */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are scope rules for braces? Wow. I've never seen this before. Also, I'm assuming that a variable cannot be initialized with a declaration, and only with a definition? For example `extern int x = some number;` seems to be illegal.

Comment: Thank you for the article as well.

Comment: @Spellbinder2050 ofcourse braces are the ROOTS of the topic "Scope Rules". You need to read more about them :) and yeah `extern int i = value` is illegal because you cannot initialize a variable which is extern(it has been initiazalized somewhere in the external scope.) Happy Coding

Comment: I thought initialization of a variable meant giving it a value? That's false? A variable definition doesn't have to be given a value. Also, I thought scope rules had to do with the functions themselves. Thanks for clearing that up also. :)

Comment: You are absolutely right about your perception of initialization and declaration. Still confused?? Well i have another article for u :)       http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/

Answer (score 3):

Example 1:

```
int x; // declares and defines global variable

int main()
{
   int x; // declares and defines *new* local variable, which hides (shadows) the global variable **in this scope**
}
```

Example 2:

```
int main()
{
   extern int x; // declares variable that will refer to variable defined *somewhere*
}

int x;
```

Example 3:

```
int x; // declares and defines global variable

int main()
{
   extern int x; // redundant, declares variable that will refer to variable defined *somewhere*, but it is already visible in this scope
}
```